# Align numerator and denominator of a fraction

Tags: align, fractions

How do I align the numerator and denominator of a fraction? I am looking for something that achieves the following psuedocode:

```
\frac{a^2 & b}{c & d}
```

(The b and d should be aligned vertically on top of one another.)

Comment: How should the `a^2` and `c` items be aligned relative to each other? Both left-aligned, centered, or right-aligned, or something else entirely? Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also want `a` on top of `c`, you can simply add a `\hfill` between `c` and `d`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{a^2 b}{c\hfill d}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, instead, you want `a^2` on top of `c`, also add a `\hfill` before `c`:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{$a^2$}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{a^2 b}{\hfill c\hfill d}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a last possibility, but I don't think it is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{$a^2$}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{a^2 b}{\hfill c d}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with [mathpartir](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/)
package. You can use `\inferrule` for typesetting logical inference rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{document}

\inferrule{a \\ b}{c \\ d}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, `mathpartir.sty` is not on CTAN, so a pointer to it would make for a better answer. Another minor point: the `minimal` class should not be used for examples; better using `article`.